# Emojis in NSStatusItem title are dark tinted when using Light Mode on Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, appkit, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

When I try to use emojis in `NSStatusItem` title on macOS Catalina and below they get some kind of dark tint. But in Dark Mode it seems to look as expected in newer versions.

[image: Side by side comparison of same code between macOS versions (image)]

Also when `NSMenu` selected it look as expected: [image: When selected (image)]

Here is how I create it:

```swift
var sItem: NSStatusItem = NSStatusItem()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    sItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    self.sItem.button!.title = " " + outsideTemp + "°C    " + roomTemp + "°C"
}
```

```swift
func setupMenu() {
    // Initialize the menu items
    let menu = NSMenu()
        
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Open in browser", action: #selector(AppDelegate.openInBrowser(_:)), keyEquivalent: "o"))
        
    menu.addItem(notifyEnabler)
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit tempApplet", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))
        
    sItem.menu = menu
}
```